# Apply CSS class based on media query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm using Bootstrap 3. What's the best approach to apply different CSS classes based on media queries? I need to apply Bootstrap col-xs classes when it's a mobile device but only apply a custom CSS class when it's the desktop version (md, lg). Right now I have 2 divs and one gets visible based on media queries but I don't want to have the DIV repeated because of that.

I know I can apply col-md and col-lg to a DIV and I'm doing it in many places but this case is different. In mobile devices I want to apply col-xs-2 but in the desktop version I need to make it behave like a table so I use display:table.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how these get applied and used. You can use col-md-x and col-sm-x etc on the same element. If you want to hide one in particular on a certain media query, you can use the utilities like hidden-xs, hidden-md, hidden-sm, etc

Comment: I know I can apply both and I'm doing it in many places but this case is different. In mobile devices I want to apply col-xs-2 but in the desktop version I need to make it behave like a table so I use display:table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the col-xs-2 on the div, and add a custom media query to take when screen fits the col-lg-* size.

For example you have this setup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2 custom-lg-col">
           .....
       </div>
       .....
   </div>
</div>
```

then you can add this to your styles file:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .custom-lg-col {
    width:...;
    display:table;
    ......
  }
}
```

But you can also leave the col-lg-2 and just add a custon class like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-lg-2 only-desk-class">
           .....
       </div>
       .....
   </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .only-desk-class {
    width:...;
    display:table;
    ......
  }
}
```

If you don't want to change the col-lg-* default style, just apply your custom div to the content inside..

Comment: This is what I needed, the key was to override width property. In my case I set it to '' to take the default value.

Answer (score 4):

use [`matchmedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) javascript if statement. Also a better idea to use the `Monderizer` library which will handle this functionality a lot better.

```
if (window.matchMedia('your_query').matches){
 //add class
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned about matchmedia.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add different classes through CSS using media queries, however you can listen to the `resize` event on window, using JavaScript, and add classes to various elements when a certain width or height threshold is reached.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1400) {
        // Add classes to elements.
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know if there's a better way to handle it. I was thinking about a class that gets set based on media elements.

Comment: I'm not too sure about Bootstrap specifically, however your best bet is probably just writing media queries, that simply sets styles. Maybe even better would be to modify the Bootstrap media queries.